# How to fit a-plane to the a-canvas

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I'm trying to fit a `<a-plane>` to the a-frame canvas.

I've managed to get the necessary params:

```
   scene = document.querySelector('a-scene');
   width = scene.canvas.width;
   height = scene.canvas.height;
```

I can't find a solid anwser regarding the correlation between pixels and meters, so i found a ratio of `zPosition/590` which seems to work well on 720p and 1080p, but something is not linear, the distance between the window and the plane is different when the window is small, and when it's big. 
Tried some experiments [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/j2ovcmxy/).

Anyone tried something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `<a-camera>` is a [THREE.PerspectiveCamera](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/cameras/PerspectiveCamera), here is a [diagram](http://irfu.cea.fr/Projets/PYMSES/_images/pymses_pespective_camera.png).
I think there several important attributes, `fov`, `near`, `far`, `aspect(canvas.width / canvas.height)`.

If we know the distance from the camera to the plane, we can calculate the width and height the plane should be.

You can attach the `foo` component to `<a-plane>` tags:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo',{
schema : {},
dependencies :["position" , "rotation"],
init:function(){
    this.camera = this.el.sceneEl.camera;
    /*get the absolute distance from the camera to the plane,
    the reason why I use Vector3 instead of this.camera.getWorldPosition() is the camera position had not initlized when this component initialized. 
    */
    this.distance = this.el.object3D.getWorldPosition().distanceTo(new THREE.Vector3(0,1.6,0));
    var height = 2 * this.distance * Math.tan(this.camera.fov / 2 / 180 * Math.PI);
    var width = height * this.camera.aspect;
    //get the plane's absolute height and width
    height = height / this.el.object3D.children[0].getWorldScale().y;
    width = width / this.el.object3D.children[0].getWorldScale().x;
    this.el.setAttribute("width",width);
    this.el.setAttribute("height",height);
    this.el.object3D.children[0].lookAt(this.camera.getWorldPosition());
}
```

});

Need to be improved:

1. dynamically get camera's world position, the plane's world scale also.
2. when the camera isn't looking at the plane, relocate the plane(a little bit complicated).

Comment: i get the idea, but i quite can't seem to make it work https://jsfiddle.net/cpg890nm/

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski I planed to write a complete jsfiddle example, but I failed, I can't configure why, and I can't debug on it. It works outside.

Comment: managed to make it work, i can't edit your anwser, the only 'error' is the lookAt(), the camera should look at the plane, not the plane at the camera. :https://jsfiddle.net/cpg890nm/1/ nonetheless i had to make a couple workarounds, gj with the aspect/fov idea

Comment: Thas's awesome!