# aframe viewport changes and positioning of entities

Tags: aframe

I need some help. For a project on whihc I am working on we use aframe. At this moment there is no need for VR, but we are working on 3d spaces.

I need two ' buttons' on the side of my scene. The user needs to see them the whole time.

Because of that in added the 'buttons as entities as child of the camera. Works like a charm. But when I change the viewport. Smaller screen ,mobile etc. you can't see them anymore the position changes.

Is there anyway to prevent this?

This is the code.

```html
<a-entity camera look-controls>
     <a-entity position="3 1 -2" >
         <a-entity id="fullScreen" geometry="primitive: circle; radius: 
0.1;" position=" 0 0.5 0"  material="src:#fullIco; transparent: true; opacity: 0.5; " fullscreen> </a-entity>
 <a-entity id="shareScene" geometry="primitive: circle; radius: 0.1;" position=" 0 0.25 0" material="src:#shareIco; transparent: true; opacity: 0.5; "sharescene> </a-entity>
       </a-entity>
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxgWQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If You're not using VR, how about using normal buttons positioned over the a-frame canvas ?

Create a `<div>`, or `<button>` with a `fixed` position, anywhere you want it to be, and make it execute your code `onclick`. Like this:

```
<button onclick="changesphere()">
```

---

You can access the a-frame entities with queryselectors, and use them like any other DOM elements.

So just define your function like this:

```
var changesphere = function() {
 if (document.querySelector("a-sphere").getAttribute("color") !== "blue")  {
  document.querySelector("a-sphere").setAttribute("color", "blue");
 } else {
  document.querySelector("a-sphere").setAttribute("color", "green");
 }
}
```

Check out my example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cgm3ure2/5/).

Comment: Thnx for you answer. I was  hoping that I could do this in the scene ;-).

Comment: @Danielvanderstam360foto i was trying to achieve something similar, fit a `<a-plane>` to the visible canvas, regardless of the viewport, check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974596/how-to-fit-a-plane-to-the-a-canvas